# Can I use a JWT for both Authentication & Data Transmission

Tags: authentication, web-application, web-service, jwt

I think I have a high level understanding of what a JWT is and how it works. 
I would now like to apply it to a use case, namely that the token would be used for authentication purposes, and passing along some data with it.

eg - a request is made to the server, and the bearer token represents both authentication information and a payload in one trip. Is this in alignment with best practices for JWT?

Comment: What kind of data? What kind of server architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Since JWTs are passed via headers, I would recommend a size of 5-7kb. For auth tokens, wrap them in http-only cookies, and use a seperate token for the payload. This is because http-only cookies are not readable by clientside JS. Sorry, would make this a comment but I don't have enough points. Hope this helps :)